# Solution/hack to render a non-closing tag to browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Backstory**
React doesn't like HTML comment tags but I need to render them as I am trying to put together a email builder using React (with Redux). Emails use a lot of inline conditional statements to fix errors in platforms such as Outlook.

The below function fixes part of my problem for me and allows the use of custom tags to render HTML comment tags in react.

**Example usage:**

```
<react-comment>Lorem ipsum dolar</react-comment>
//above is equal to below
<!--Lorem ipsum dolar-->
```

**The function this uses:**

```
var proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype, {
    name: { get: function () { return 'React HTML Comment'; } },
    createdCallback: {
        value: function () {
            this.is = '';
            this.removeAttribute('is');
        }
    },
    attachedCallback: {
        value: function () {
            this.outerHTML = '<!--' + this.textContent + '-->';
        }
    }
});
document.registerElement('react-comment', { prototype: proto });
```

**Example component I need to modify**
(Note: The curly brackets wrapping the conditional statements allow the component to render, but the statements will be missing in the browser.)

```
class Test extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        {/*[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        <table width="604" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr>
        <td width="288" valign="top">
        <![endif]*/}
        <element>
            HTML that is being wrapped
        </element>
        {/*[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>        
        </td>         
        </tr>        
        </table>       
        <![endif]*/}
        )
    }
}
```

**My current closest attempt - not working for reason stated in title and below**
Here I am trying only the opening tags inside of the conditional statement to test.

```
<react-comment>[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]></react-comment>
<react-comment><table width="604" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"></react-comment>
<react-comment><tr></react-comment>
<react-comment><td width="288" valign="top"></react-comment>
<react-comment>[endif]</react-comment>
```

But ofcourse now the `<table>`, `<td>` and `<tr>` are no longer commented out prior to rendering and won't render because they don't close and cant close on the other side of the HTML elements I want to wrap because they are already nested within a closed "element".

I've been thinking about a solution to this for a while and can't come up with anything.